# Get success status AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, events, amazon-ses, status

### Prerequisites

I use [AWS SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/Welcome.html) to send an email with [event publishing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-using-event-publishing.html) to track the delivery status.

### Problem

I'm looking for an event to make sure that an email is successfully sent to the end-user.

### Description

Following AWS documentation, this type is suitable:

> **Deliveries** – Amazon SES successfully delivered the email to the
> recipient's mail server.

However, this event I get also in case **Hard bounces**.

For example, email status flow is:

- **Sends** -> **Deliveries** - in case of successfull delivery
- **Sends** -> **Deliveries** -> **Hard bounces** - in case I provide invalid *recipient name*, e.g. invalid@domain.com or 1234567890@domain.com

I don't expect **Hard bounces** after **Deliveries**.
If this behavior is correct then I need some additional event for sure success.
Something like this is expected in case of successfull delivery:

- **Sends** -> **Deliveries** -> **Success**

I know that there are other "success" events like **Opens**, **Clicks**, **Subscriptions**, but they require additional action from the end-user.

### Implementation details

I use [Verified identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/verify-addresses-and-domains.html) as an email sender.

A [configuration set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/using-configuration-sets.html) is used to redirect status events to [SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html).

Finally, [SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/welcome.html) is subscribed to this SNS to have all events in one place.

I tried several ways to send an email:

- Java code using [AWS SES SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-an-email-using-sdk-programmatically.html)
- [Sending simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-an-email-from-console.html#send-email-simulator) with predefined and custom recipient's

The result is the same (as described above)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is impossible to have a `Success` status because AWS cannot guarantee when the recipient mail server will reply with a `Hard Bounce`. You yourself have to define how long to you want to wait until you consider a delivery as successful. For example, if no hard bounce after 5 minutes, then it is a success.

If your use case is for analytics, I will simply capture more event types (for example log both Deliveries and Hard Bounces), and then count my success as Count of Deliveries - Count of Hard Bounces.

If your use case is for event-driven workloads, we need to define first what is considered a `Success`. For example, if we define `Success` as no `Hard Bounce` after 5 minutes, we can configure a Lambda function to trigger 5 minutes after a Delivery event. In the function, check if a subsequent Bounce event occurred. If not, the delivery is considered successful and then you can proceed to do what you want to do.

Comment: This is a good idea to use delay, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got from aws support about delivery status of an email.

> Amazon SES will continue making several delivery attempts until
> receiving a successful response from the recipient mail server, or
> until 840  minutes elapse. If Amazon SES is still unable to deliver
> the email/message during this period, it stops sending the email and
> will then return a bounce message/notification.

According to this you can't be sure about the `bounce` or any other status within 5 minutes.
AWS does not have visibility to confirm if the Recipient Mail Server was able to deliver the message to the recipient email address when you get a `250 OK`(it's confirmation that aws has delivered the message to recipient's mail server).
So there is no way you can be sure.